# Unable to access Admin URL after migrating settings

Tags: migration

After migrating the setting my admin URL is inaccessible. Front-end is working fine.

I've invoked the settings.xml file to skip but still results in the same issue.

So far... 
I've checked the env.php and all appears to be in order 
I've also cleared my cache but same result

Thank you

Comment: have got backup your store files?

Comment: please share URL details

Comment: Apologies, I'm a newbie to Magento. What directory are you referring to by 'store files'? The URL to the main site is: http://bellesfruit.co.uk/ this appears to be working OK, however, as mentioned the issue lies when trying to load the backend webpage.

Comment: please access to file app/etc/env.php and check again whether frontName in backend is correct?

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Yes, front name within env.php is correct, though I fear there may be another reference that I'm missing. If you have any other ideas they would be well received.